# CentOS Password Change

Tags: centos, encryption, passwd

I am looking for changing my centos password by using passwd with encryption.

echo "Password1" | passwd --stdin username

But if I'm using with above method, user will see what my password is. Does someone know how can I make "Password1" to be encrypted?

Comment: I presume you're trying to do this in a batched manner?  If not, how about just `passwd username`?

Comment: I'm trying to do remotely and require to use only one line.

Comment: Why?  I don't mean to criticise, but questions like this often reveal underlying assumptions or constraints that are questionable at best.

Comment: Do you mean it is easy or you don't know?

Comment: Neither.  I mean that I suspect there is no good reason to do it in one line; if there is, the nature of those business constraints may affect possible solutions (at the moment, I'm thinking sending a `crypt`ed string to `usermod -p`).  Unless, of course, this is a homework question; we don't totally frown on those, but it's considered polite to declare them in the question.

Comment: oh, we have server as the control panel and alot clients connect via VPN. So we need to send command to those client to change password.

Comment: Why does that mean it has to be done in one line?  If what you really mean is "*I need to set a password in a non-interactive session*", that would be a subtly (but signficantly) different question.

Comment: Sorry, I may use the wrong expression then. just want to make it simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, I think your best bet is to pass the hashed password to the client, instead of the plaintext one.

**Locally**, hash the password with

hashpass=`openssl passwd -1 -salt sssss ppppppppppp`

Then tell the **remote** client

`usermod -p $hashpass username`

where `sssss` is a random salt, `ppppppppppp` is the desired password, and `username` is the user whose password is to be reset.  Ensuring the correct passage of `$hashpass` is also something you will need to attend to.

If you run the `openssl` command on the command line, you'll see how it returns a hashed password string rather than the plaintext password.  This is still not completely secure, but a lot better than having a plaintext password on the CLI.  I also note that this uses `md5` hashing, which is considered weak.  I can't currently find a way of producing a `sha`-hashed password from the command line; if you can, that would be better.